# Many items in single order, SQL table design

Tags: sql, database-design, datatable

I got one order table, when user come to the store they could purchase more than one item for example. may i know what is the best practices to perform such record action ? is that each item order one row in order table or mix all into one row in order table ?

Let say, Customer A purchase 3 items from store. then will be 3 row in order table ? or 1 row in order table with all details and separate order with delimiter ?

My designed structure is like this::

```
tblOrder
    OrderID (Primary Key)
    UserID
    TotalPrice

tblOrderItem
    OrderItemID (Primary Key)
    OrderID (Referencing tblOrder)
    Quantity
    ItemID (Referencing tblItem)
    TotalPrice
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to maintain 3 rows, because it will be easy for you to maintain further.

**Updated:**

@SLim, The structure is looking perfect for the situation now. You will proceed further with this.

Comment: something was edited =D can you please judge is that correct ? Thx =D

Answer (score 1):

Without question, each order should have its own row in the database table.

Otherwise, for example, if you wanted to find all orders where a particular item was purchased -- how would you do it? It's much easier if there's a single item per row.

More than that, this is the approach taken by larger e-commerce sites. If you're interested in learning to develop software professionally you must learn the best practices.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion =D That is... wondering how to make the application better =D